# Is "compress OS Drive" worth it on SSD?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, compression

My SSD is running out of disk space, and I see that "Compress your OS drive" is suggested as a means to save some disk space.

[image: disk cleanup]

### **My questions:**

1. I'm not sure whether there are any performance penalty associating with compressing the OS drive.
2. And I'm not even sure whether this option is the same with "Compress this drive to save disk space" at the C drive property as per below. [This option does seem to come with performance penalty](https://superuser.com/q/567528/522).

[image: disk properties]

Edit:

My PC information:

1. Windows 10
2. 12GB RAM
3. 4 Cores with Intel i7

Comment: Is this on an 8-16 core monster desktop, or a single core atom netbook? I'm pretty sure there'll be some performance penalty, not sure if it'll be noticeable or not. [This article from 2011 might be interesting](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-ntfs-compression,3073-11.html) & mentions "*With information being compressed on the fly, you're consuming more of an SSD's available write cycles than if you were writing the files uncompressed. This could have negative implications on the drive's endurance*" but it's not obvious why. And I thought I read SSD's might do their own compression?

Comment: @Xen2050, it's a 4 core system

Comment: @Xen2050 that's about NTFS compression for *general purpose files* that can be read and write constantly, not CompactOS which compresses *read-only system files*, so no write-amplification is involved and write cycle doesn't further change. And worrying about drive wear nowadays is pretty much nonsense, because wear-leveling algorithms are increasingly good, and the total data write is enough for at least 4-8 years even if you write hundreds of GBs a day, that's why modern SSDs have 5-year warranties. I have an old workstation from 2009 or 2012 and its SSD just passed half its life

Comment: Just get a bigger drive or add a second drive, compression is way more trouble than its worth.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The two compress options aren't the same, but more on that later. The first thing to note is that **compressing data is not the best solution** when the drive is full. NTFS will suffer badly from lack of space, because there are no more good places to allocate new files or move old files around and fragmentation will increase. Especially when it begins to use the [reserved space](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/174619/how-ntfs-reserves-space-for-its-master-file-table-mft) for the [MFT](https://superuser.com/q/186573/241386) then the MFT might become fragmented and worse things may happen

So at first some other things need to be done:

- [**Reduce pagefile size**](https://web.archive.org/web/20181227061244/https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2013/01/how-to-change-the-size-of-virtual-memory-pagefile-sys-on-windows-8-or-windows-server-2012/). Your system will crawl to death if just 1-3GB of pagefile is used. But you can't disable it entirely (at least not a good idea), so a lower limit of 1GB and upper limit of 4GB might be a fine choice. That will ***save you a few GBs*** compared to the default setting. You can add more page files on other drives if available
- **Reduce hiberfil.sys size**. Open cmd as admin and run `powercfg /h /size 40` to set the size to 40% of your RAM. From Windows 7 onward it defaults to [75% the amount of RAM](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/7/7E7662CF-CBEA-470B-A97E-CE7CE0D98DC2/HiberFootprint.docx), so setting it to 50% will ***save you 3GB of disk space***. You can also *turn it off completely* with `powercfg /h off` if you don't need hibernation, or if you want to turn off hibernation while still enabling fast boot then use `powercfg /h /type reduced` which shrinks the file to only 20%
- [Clean up the WinSxS folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder) with the [`DISM` command](https://superuser.com/a/594216/241386). For more information read [How to Reduce the Size of Your WinSXS Folder](https://www.howtogeek.com/174705/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-your-winsxs-folder-on-windows-7-or-8/)
- **Check your data usage** and move/remove some unnecessary files

  You can use some tools like [WizTree](https://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wiztree-finds-the-files-and-folders-using-the-most-disk-space-on-your-hard-drive/), [TreeSize](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/?language=EN) or [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/). You'll be surprised to see how big some files/folders are, esp. some temp and cache folders. WizTree is likely the fastest and more correct one because it reads information directly from the MFT. Remember to run them as admin

  For more suggestions see [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/8248/241386) or [The Four Best Free Tools to Analyze Hard Drive Space on Your Windows PC](https://www.howtogeek.com/113012/10-best-free-tools-to-analyze-hard-drive-space-on-your-windows-pc/)
- If you have another HDD then don't store too many unnecessary things on the system drive. Leave it for apps and files that need fast access

  - Move the documents folders to another drive
  - Move the [store app install folder and save folder](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-apps-separate-drive-windows-10)
  - Some other folders can also be moved by changing some configurations, or by creating a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). For example many folders in Windows\System32 or Program Files can be moved to HDD. Some tutorials on that

    - [Moving Windows folders around with Junction links (mklink)](https://superuser.com/q/931992/241386)
    - [Using mklink on Windows to move data off of SSDs](https://davidzych.com/using-mklink-on-windows-to-move-data-off-of-ssds/)
    - [How to Reclaim Space Used by Games with Symbolic Links](https://www.guidingtech.com/reclaim-space-used-games-with-symbolic-links-windows-10/)
    - [How to Maximize Space on your SSD using Symbolic Links](https://www.jodyhatton.com/ssd-hard-drive-windows-7-winsxs/)
- Delete Windows.old if you don't need to roll back to the previous version, or back it up and remove it

  - [How to copy windows.old folder to another drive?](https://superuser.com/q/949416/241386)
  - [Copy/Move Windows.old Folder to External Hard Drive](https://www.easeus.com/todo-backup-resource/copy-windows-old-folder-to-external-hard-drive.html)

Just doing the first 2 steps above saves you tons of space immediately. Then after doing everything if more space is still needed then just compact the OS. By deleting files first you also make it faster to compress the OS. The performance difference is *often* negligible

The *CompactOS* feature does indeed **worth it** on small SSDs compared to HDDs. My old laptop has a 1TB HDD with a 32GB SSD cache. I've tried installing Windows onto the 32GB SSD and it ran *noticeably smoother* than on the HDD+cache

---

Regarding your questions:

> I'm not sure whether there are any performance penalty associating with compressing the OS drive.

**Compressing files *always* have a CPU time penalty**. That doesn't mean that it'll be slow though, since on slow storage devices like HDDs that penalty might be far less than the wasted time on accessing/reading the data from HDD. That's why sometimes compressing easily-compressed data will make it faster to access. One example is that hibernation in newer Windows compresses data before writing to disk, which makes shutdown much faster because the CPU can compress faster than the drive can write

The difference may be less obvious on SSDs, but there's no way to know that for sure except benchmarking for your specific situation. Each use case is different, and not all disks are created equal. For example old SSDs may run at only ~200MB/s which is just about as fast as an HDD nowadays (but their obvious advantage is the very fast *access time* and high [IOPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS)), whereas newer algorithms like [LZ4](https://github.com/lz4/lz4) (which is used in Linux's [zram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram)) or [Zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd) can sustain ~2-5GB/s which is even faster than modern SSDs. See

- [With SSDs and Compact, Windows can speed up even more](https://ttcshelbyville.wordpress.com/2016/07/31/with-ssds-and-compact-windows-can-speed-up-even-more/) for an example where CompactOS boosts system performance
- [I tested 25 games against the Windows Compact function: 51GB more free space, and all the games run with no performance issues](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/76hj26/i_tested_25_games_against_the_windows_compact/)
- [Gaming & NTFS Compression?](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcgaming/comments/44b4ue/gaming_ntfs_compression/)

There's often no need to worry, because Windows will do a benchmark while installing to assess whether CompactOS should be enabled or not. Although after installing apps and things that benchmark result may not be correct anymore and you may want to do a reassessment yourself

> And I'm not even sure whether this option is the same with "Compress this drive to save disk space" at the C drive property as per below

Basically both use the compression feature of NTFS and can be configured by `compact.exe`, but there are many major differences

- The *"Compress your OS drive"* (i.e. CompactOS) feature uses the newly introduced compression algorithms [**XPRESS* and LZX**](https://superuser.com/a/1149911/241386) in Windows 10's NTFS. They're designed for efficient storage for "static" files that don't change much (like executables)

  OTOH the *"Compress this drive to save disk space"* feature uses LZNT1 algorithm and is designed for compressing frequently changed data files for optimum performance. That means it'll be faster but the compression ratio will not be as high. It's like checking the [*"Compress contents to save disk space"* option](https://www.howtogeek.com/133264/how-to-use-ntfs-compression-and-when-you-might-want-to/) for all files and folders on the drive

  [image: Compress contents to save disk space]
- Files compacted by CompactOS will **not be marked as compressed** (either [shown in blue](https://superuser.com/q/301690/241386) or with [double arrows](https://superuser.com/q/1001970/241386)) if that feature is enabled
- CompactOS compresses [*selected system files*](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/03/windows-10-shaves-off-gigabytes-with-selective-system-file-compression/?comments=1&vs=b), while NTFS whole-disk-compression compresses *every file* on the disk

In fact you can use the new algorithms for CompactOS for any user files, but you can't do on-the-fly editing on them, as they're designed for static read-only files like mentioned above. Writing to those files will uncompress them. For more information about that as you can read [NTFS compressed folders: is it possible to tweak compression ratio?](https://superuser.com/a/1149911/241386)

The random on-the-fly write ability also makes the *"Compress this drive to save disk space"* even worse for your use case, because it **increases fragmentation significantly**. CompactOS compresses the whole file (AFAIK) like a *.cab or *.wim file so you'll get a contiguous file. OTOH NTFS transparent compression works by [splitting the file to 16-cluster chunks](https://superuser.com/q/1136329/241386) and [compress them separately](http://www.forensicfocus.com/index.php?name=Content&pid=179). Each chunk will be a fragment after that, which makes your contiguous file now has tons of holes between the chunks.

You may think "why worry about that" but **SSD's complete immunity to fragmentation is a myth!** For fast operations and small metadata size modern file systems store files as [extents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extent_(file_systems)) which is a file's contiguous section on disk, so each fragment will be stored as a separate extent. Hence a file with 1000 fragments will consume more space in the MFT for the metadata compared to a 2-fragment one, and the CPU also needs more time to parse them to get the next block of data. As a result Windows defragmenter still does some *mild* defragmentation for SSD drives to optimize metadata usage

## Further reading:

- [File Compression versus Compact OS in Win 10?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/file-compression-versus-compact-os-in-win-10/b1ba7598-4b26-4475-a0b1-122db7221c00?auth=1)
- [How can Windows 10 function on as little as 32 GB of disk space?](https://superuser.com/q/1011288/241386)

The link given by [Xen2050](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-ntfs-compression,3073-3.html) is also good. It shows that even with the drive compression feature the difference is not that much, and in some cases it'll be faster, as I mentioned above