# Pagefile regenerated on C drive every time on startup despite pagefile configuration being changed to list C as "no pagefile" & D as "system managed"

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, storage, pagefile

Due to having low space on my C drive (which I've reserved for the operating system) I recently made the following changes to my pagefile configuration

[image]

However, nothing at changed in my C drive in terms of space (even after countless restarts) and the pagefile is still there (although I now have a copy on the D drive it seems).

[image]

Furthermore, I now get this warning everytime my boot up my computer

[image]

Now that I have changed the pagefile configuration for it to appear only in the D drive (which is a different drive altogether), should I be deleting it from the C drive? Based on the "date modified" it seems it is regenerated on the C every time I boot up my computer, while on the D drive it still lists the "date modified" as the day I originally made this change.

I would appreciate if someone can guide me to a fix for this issue. Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion doesn't solve your problem.. but you *could* try making the smallest possible size on c: .. Is d: an internal drive?

Comment: Disabling the page file on C: means you will not get memory dumps on BSOD errors. I think it's worth it to use a few gigabytes for that.

Comment: [see this](https://superuser.com/a/1406376/241386) for more ways to free up space on the C drive

Comment: did you try this [How to Fix Windows Created a Temporary Paging File](https://www.minitool.com/news/windows-created-temporary-paging-file.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Windows created a temporary paging file" message after every startup](https://superuser.com/questions/1717088/windows-created-a-temporary-paging-file-message-after-every-startup)

Answer (score 0):

The message seems to suggest the file on D may have an issue.

Try:

- disable the pagefile on D, reboot;
- remove the pagefile.sys from D if it still exists after reboot;
- (optional reboot);
- set you pagefile back to D and remove the C pagefile