# "Windows created a temporary paging file" message after every startup

Tags: windows-10, pagefile

Despite my best effort researching and debugging this problem on my own, I haven't been able to solve it.

Some basic info to start:

- I'm running the latest version of Windows 10 (no pending updates at the time of writing).
- I have two 500 GB drives (`C:` and `D:`).
- I want to put my page file on the `D:` drive (where there is more available space).
- Here are my current virtual memory settings:
  [image: Virtual memory (page file) settings for both C and D drives]

Now, the problem. Every time I boot, I get this message:

[image: "Windows created a temporary paging file..." error]

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get this message to stop appearing. And I don't know what kind of "problem" Windows is running into.

Here's a list of everything I've tried so far:

- Restarting (many times)
- Turning off page files for both drives (and restarting afterwards). (The pagefile.sys file disappears from both drives, but the error still comes up.)
- System File Checker (`sfc /scannow`)
- Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool (`Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`)
- Check Disk tool on both volumes (`chkdsk C: /R` and `chkdsk D: /R`)
- Repair installation of Windows 10 (in-place upgrade using the "keep files and apps" setting)

Any other advice on what I should try, or where I should look for more details on what's going wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you're trying not to have a page file on the system partition. Just let Windows have what it wants.

Comment: I've seen this myself, and it was a matter of an existing pagefile that was somehow corrupted and thus a new one could not be made. But yeah, there needs to be a pagefile on C too, even if its just a small one.

Comment: ~24 GB free space on a ~500 GB drive is perhaps somewhat too low: aim for maybe 20% free space so that it can keep running smoothly.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I agree with that, but it's not always easy. I decided to move a couple file groups around so that the OS had most of the free space and the D drive is nearly full instead.

Comment: @DanielB I know Windows Server it doesn't have a problem with the page file not being on the OS disk, but Windows Desktop might be different. In the end I rearranged my files to move the free space and put the page file back on the C drive.

Answer (score 10):

I found a working solution here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/move-pagefile-to-another-disk-windows-keeps-using/b80fed24-12ff-4482-a45d-fdbae4f08987

> No matter what you do it keeps creating a temporary page file on C:\ the solution to this is if you have enabled Bitlocker Drive Encryption it  creates and enables the registry key "PagefileOnOsVolume" and set it to enabled. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929820/bitlocker-drive-encryption-bde-enables-the-pagefileonosvolume-registry

> Even if you disable bitlocker and decrypt the drives this registry key stays set as enabled bypassing any attempts to move the page file to another partition / drive.   If you set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PagefileOnOsVolume to 0 then reboot you will be able to set your page file to none on your OS drive and move it properly to another partition / hd.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you so much! This did the trick! I was having so much trouble moving the 60gb pagefile.sys from my OS C:\ drive (which has Bitlocker) to another internal hard drive. Changing registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PagefileOnOsVolume` from `1` to `0` then rebooting solved it!!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem and found a (dissatisfying) fix for it.

My observations were:

- Windows wants a page file on `C:` (as @Daniel B wrote in the comments)
- The secondary page file must have a fixed size, otherwise windows won't use it

Therefore you have to create a small (16MB - 32MB or so) page file on `C:`. Then you can create a second page file on another drive. The second page file must have a fixed size, otherwise windows won't use it properly.

With the following settings, I get a page file on a secondary drive working:

[image: Virtual Memory]

Comment: My machine doesn't seem to accept 16MB - 32MB so I make it to 1000 - 2000. It works for now

Comment: Is such a huge 32GB file necessary?